# Cause of Infinite Loop? (iterative inorder traversal implementation) C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, traversal, inorder

Question: Implement Inorder Traversal iteratively.

My Attempt: (results in an infinite loop that I haven't been able to debug) any help or suggestions greatly appreciated

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
    
    public:
    
        vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
            
            //iterative sol:
            vector<int> sol;
            stack<TreeNode*> dfs;
            dfs.push(root);
            unordered_set<TreeNode*> visited;
            visited.insert({root});
            TreeNode* temp;
            
            while (!dfs.empty()) {
                
                if (dfs.top()->left != nullptr && visited.find(dfs.top()->left) == visited.end()) {
                    dfs.push(dfs.top()->left);
                    visited.insert({dfs.top()->left});
                }
                else {
                    sol.push_back(dfs.top()->val);
                    temp = dfs.top();
                    dfs.pop();
                    
                    if (temp->right != nullptr && visited.find(temp->right) == visited.end()) {
                        dfs.push(temp->right);
                        visited.insert({temp->right});
                    }
                }     
                          
            }
            
            return sol;
            
        }
};
```

EDIT: I don't have the specific internal definitions of the TreeNode, but if you want to run the problem, checkout: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem :

```
dfs.push(dfs.top()->left);
visited.insert(dfs.top()->left);
```

You are pushing to stack  (then `dfs.top()` will change) and then accessing `dfs.top()->left` in the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the stack in the first line here

```
  dfs.push(dfs.top()->left);
  visited.insert({dfs.top()->left});
```

what you want to do is to mark the previous `dfs.top()->left` as visited, but you are adding more element on top of the stack and thus the new `dfs.top()` is a different one.

To solve this problem you should use store the previous `dfs.top()->left` in a different variable.

As a best practice, the variable or object you are working on should be immutable, since the stack is not immutable don't use its `top` while inserting into it or doing some other computations. Instead store your required variable into something immutatble like `temp` here

```
 temp = dfs.top();
 if (temp->left != nullptr && visited.find(temp->left) == visited.end()) {
    dfs.push(temp->left);
    visited.insert({temp->left});
  }
  else {
    sol.push_back(dfs.top()->val);
    dfs.pop();
                    
    if (temp->right != nullptr && visited.find(temp->right) == visited.end()) {
       dfs.push(temp->right);
       visited.insert({temp->right});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It only takes 2 simple rules to implement an iterative in-order traversal.

If you're at node X, then:

1. If X has a right child, then move to the right child, and follow as many left links as possible to find the next node.
2. Otherwise, find the closest ancestor of X on the right, i.e., the closest ancestor whose left subtree contains X.  If there is no such ancestor then you're done.

If your tree doesn't have parent links, then you'll need a stack to store the right ancestors, but there's no need for a visited set:

```
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* tree) {
    vector<int> ret;
    stack<TreeNode *> nextParents;
    for(;tree; tree = tree.left) {
        nextParents.push(tree);
    }
    while(!nextParents.empty()) {
        tree = nextParents.pop();
        ret.push_back(tree->val);
        for(tree = tree.right; tree; tree = tree.left) {
            nextParents.push(tree);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```